# Rails render regular erb partial to active admin layout (arb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, erb, arbre

I'm trying to add a view that LOOKS like active admin, but doesn't need to take advantage of active admin's automatic page creations (in fact I can't because I'm not using a model for these views). In my controller, I've added

```
render "reports/index", layout: "active_admin"
```

I've seen this done in several other forums. However, I'm getting this error: `undefined local variable or method 'view_factory' for :Arbre::Context`
which I'm assuming is because I'm not using a full active admin page object or something. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a model then use [a custom page](https://activeadmin.info/10-custom-pages.html).